# How to remove ambiguity from the meaning of an "executive" title in a corporate context?

Tags: resume, linkedin, title

I have seen the word "executive" being used for completely opposite levels of seniority:

Someone is a "senior executive" means that one is a director or senior manager at a business.

Someone is a "senior sales executive" means someone is a senior individual contributor in a sales function. And "sales executive" is the lowest level in the hierarchy.

How to put clarity when explaining these different uses of the same word, e.g. in a Linkedin profile. I would like to say I am a middle (and aspiring senior) manager... what is the correct expression?

Comment: Many people think up many different titles; there are hardly any standards.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere As the Senior Executive Management Director of Business Operations of my one-person company I disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of fuzziness in those titles, not least because different organizations will have different descriptions for the same title. Or different titles for the same position. If you find anything worthwhile, let us know.

Give an exact description of your duties - that's just about the only approach that makes any sense and that works.

Comment: +1, not much more that can be said. All titles are fuzzy. Write a paragraph describing what your job actually entails.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer hiding in your question. Sales titles are *special*. If you are the sort of person who carries a quota, anyone reading your resume will replace 'executive' with the empty string. If your CV does not show you to be a person carrying a quote, they will expect 'executive' to mean 'senior' management.

There is related inflation of 'director' in marketing organizations.

So, unless you are a middle manager of *salespeople*, you have nothing to worry over.